# unable to find SceneBuilder in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, ubuntu-20.04

I am using Apache Netbeans IDE v12.5 and want to use Scene Builder for my JavaFX programs but I am unable to find the file to import Scene Builder. **tools->options->Java->JavaFX** On searching in the internet I found that the file would be in `/opt/scenebuilder/bin`, but for me it's empty.
On actually looking in the directoy, there's a **shared library** named **scenebuilder**. Is there any other way to find the or import the scenebuilder file?

Comment: You don’t need to integrate scene builder into an IDE. Use the stand-alone version from [gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download).

Comment: scenebuilder is an application.  you installed it (where you want) and tell your ide which is its installation directory.